# why is /bin/ls linking to libpthread?

Tags: shared-library, ls, coreutils

so strange, is ls multi-threaded somehow? what could `ls` possibly need libpthread for?

```
ldd /bin/ls
    linux-vdso.so.1 (0x00007ffff7fce000)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libselinux.so.1 (0x00007ffff7f57000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ffff7d65000)
    libpcre2-8.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpcre2-8.so.0 (0x00007ffff7cd2000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ffff7ccc000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x00007ffff7fcf000)
    libpthread.so.0 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0x00007ffff7ca9000)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's not `ls` itself that depends on `libpthread`. Use [`lddtree` from `pax-utils`](https://github.com/gentoo/pax-utils) (`sudo apt install pax-utils`) to see the dependency tree:

```
# lddtree /bin/ls
ls => /bin/ls (interpreter => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3)
    libselinux.so.1 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libselinux.so.1
        libpcre.so.3 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpcre.so.3
            libpthread.so.0 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libpthread.so.0
        libdl.so.2 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libdl.so.2
    libc.so.6 => /lib/arm-linux-gnueabihf/libc.so.6
    ld-linux-armhf.so.3 => /lib/ld-linux-armhf.so.3
```

`ldd` shows all shared libraries that the file links to, including indirect dependencies.