# why is /usr/bin/free opening liblzma?

Tags: free

I see the following when running `strace free`:

```
hans@devad22:~$ strace free 2>&1 | grep openat
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.8", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
openat(AT_FDCWD, "/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
(...)
```

Why is free opening a bunch of compression libraries? What does `free` need `liblzma` for?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This basically a copy of [an earlier answer of mine](https://askubuntu.com/a/1376416/158442), *mutatis mutandis*:

---

It's not `free` itself that depends on `liblzma`. Use [`lddtree` from `pax-utils`](https://github.com/gentoo/pax-utils) (`sudo apt install pax-utils`) to see the dependency tree:

```
# lddtree $(command -v free)
free => /usr/bin/free (interpreter => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1)
    libprocps.so.8 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libprocps.so.8
        libsystemd.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libsystemd.so.0
            liblzma.so.5 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblzma.so.5
            libzstd.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libzstd.so.1
            liblz4.so.1 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/liblz4.so.1
            libcap.so.2 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libcap.so.2
            libgcrypt.so.20 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgcrypt.so.20
                libgpg-error.so.0 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libgpg-error.so.0
    libc.so.6 => /lib/aarch64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6
    ld-linux-aarch64.so.1 => /lib/ld-linux-aarch64.so.1
```

`ldd` shows all shared libraries that the file links to, including indirect dependencies.

---

`free` is from [the procps collection of tools](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps), and naturally these tools use a shared library for common functionality. Some of this functionality might be used by only some procps tools, though. In this case, `ps` and other tools support systemd-related constructs (e.g., `ps` can output the systemd unit of a process). So it links to the systemd library, which in turn brings in these compression libraries. (Not sure what systemd uses them for, maybe compressing core dump files or something like that.)

However, `free` doesn't seem to use any systemd-related functionality, AFAICT. ([The source code](https://gitlab.com/procps-ng/procps/-/blob/master/src/free.c?ref_type=heads) is relatively simple, if you want to check it out.) It just happens to link to a library the links to a systemd library that links to several compression libraries.

Comment: Seems legit - and my answer was unfortunately based on assumptions. 

Comment: systemd supports compressed logs, might be related to compressed logs too

Comment: Possibly. Anyway, basically the entirety of actual `free` execution begins around `openat(AT_FDCWD, "/proc/meminfo", O_RDONLY|O_LARGEFILE)` in the `strace` output. The system calls before those are mostly various libraries setting up.